# Opencart 2x Модуль HTML Содержимое - как добавить картинку?

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

Как добавить возможность указать картинку к модулю html блок как в категории или товар

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <a href="" id="thumb-image<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="../image/<?php echo isset($module_description[$language['language_id']]['image']) ? $module_description[$language['language_id']]['image'] : ''; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" />
                  </a>
                  <input type="hidden" name="module_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][image]" value="<?php echo isset($module_description[$language['language_id']]['image']) ? $module_description[$language['language_id']]['image'] : ''; ?>" id="input-image<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

как правильно указать путь к картинки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: хотелось бы такую функцию, пример http://joxi.ru/xAeM9lKtM0BOzA -> сюда http://joxi.ru/a2XX8y9CQNdv72

Comment: чтоб каждый мог изменить картинку не ломая верстку, будет круто, если рядом будет возможность указать ширину и высоту картинки